# Tab completion not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipython

A cell:

```
import pandas as pd
%config Completer.use_jedi = False
#%config IPCompleter.greedy=True
```

Another cell:

```
df = pd.read_csv('employees.csv')
```

My configuration:

> linux mint 20
>
> python 3.8
>
> jupyter 1.0.0
>
> jedi 0.18.0
>
> ipython 7.22.0

If I type `df = pd.read<tab>`
I get a drop down list where `read_csv` is an option

If I type `emp<tab>`, It completes employee.csv.

But if I type `df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].ast<tab>`,
It does not complete astype.

Googling shows that adding `%config Completer.use_jedi = False`
or reverting back to jedi 0.17.2 or adding `#%config IPCompleter.greedy=True`
fixes autocomplete problems for many people. I have tried various combinations
of all three but it still did not work for me.

I am new to juypter notebooks so my question is: In the above
case `df['Gender']` is a dataframe column so should typing `ast<tab> yield astype`?

Regards,  Jim

Comment: try ctrl + space

Comment: I tried ctrl + space but it did not produce an expansion.